# Squid proxy server (or iptables) will not let my users send or receive mail

Tags: iptables, smtp, squid

I have an Ubuntu 10.04 box that was once configured as Squid Transparent Proxy.
Navigation was perfect: my windows clients had no troubles.

The problem I had was that users were not able send or receive mail using outlook (and outlook express).
So I've googled here and there and found out a solution:

`sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p TCP --dport 25 -j MASQUERADE`

`sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p TCP --dport 110 -j MASQUERADE`

Everything went great.

Now I've enabled squid authentication (the simple one using a text file) and my outlook and outlook express stopped working again.
I've read that the problem is not really squid related because it won't proxy smtp or pop...
But I still need to solve it.
NAT? Port forwarding?

What kind of commands should I use?

The squid server has a single NIC and can get on the internet and solve names using opendns servers witout problems.

configuration on server:
ip
**192.168.1.210**
subnet
**255.255.255.0**
gateway
**192.168.1.5**

On clients I use:
ip
**192.168.1.x**
subnet
**255.255.255.0**
gateway
**192.168.1.210**

I can add further details so please ask but I don't know what could be needed to solve the problem.

EDIT:

sudo iptables -L

`Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)`

`target     prot opt source               destination`

`fail2ban-ssh  tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            multiport dports ssh`

`Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)`

`target     prot opt source               destination`

`Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)`

`target     prot opt source               destination`

`Chain fail2ban-ssh (1 references)`

`target     prot opt source               destination`

`RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere`

sudo iptables -L -t nat

`Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)`

`target     prot opt source               destination`

`REDIRECT   tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:www redir ports 3128`

`Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)`

`target     prot opt source               destination`

`MASQUERADE  tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:smtp`

`MASQUERADE  tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:pop3`

`Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)`

`target     prot opt source               destination`

Comment: Please add output of iptables -L and iptables -L -t nat, to see what your firewall configuration looks like, and contents of /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward (should be just the number "1"). You're right that Squid should have absolutely nothing to do with it. Also please think if you changed anything other than squid authentication (did you reboot the server?) as that's what the problem may be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what exactly you're going to achieve. As far as I understand you're going to use the machine with squid as router/firewall for the following scenario:

1. allow web protocols (http/ftp) through squid only
2. allow access to smpt/pop3 from your internal network to the outside via NAT.
3. Your gateway to the internet is 192.168.1.5

Usually NAT translates from one Network (192.168.1.0/24) to another one (i.e. 84.145.77.23/32) and the other way around. So you might need to setup NAT rules on the your gateway machine 192.168.1.5 in order to work.

So that the outgoing path is:

```
client -> 192.168.1.210 ->NAT-> 192.168.1.5 ->NAT-> mailserver
```

And the incoming path for responses is:

```
mailserver -> 192.168.1.5 ->NAT-> 192.168.1.210 ->NAT-> client
```

As seen here 192.168.1.210 could be eliminated and the gateway could be configured accepting and NATing outgoing smtp/pop3 traffic from all clients and accepting outgoning http(s)/ftp traffic from 192.168.1.210 only.

Imho the second NAT between 192.168.1.210 and 192.168.1.5 might cause problems (same network) and is unnecessary.

To enable NAT in general on 192.168.1.210 please try the following first:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

change eth0 to your network interface name, if necessary.

Comment: This is absolutely what I should achieve!
Can you please provide details on the commans I should digit to obtain step 1 & 2?

Comment: I can't modify settings on the 192.168.1.5 gateway so I'd simply like the 192.168.1.210 to forward pop and smtp requests to 192.168.1.5

Comment: According to your output above, could you try to change the smtp/pop rules to use a specific interface?

Comment: I cannot edit my comment above. sorry. According to your output above, could you try to change the smtp/pop rules to use a specific interface without specific ports? With `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE`. The rules above only allow forwarding for ports 25 and 110 forth and back. But the client that established the connection would have another (random) port than 25 or 110.

Comment: Ok... So I have to digit iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE and then what do I have to do to be sure that requests coming from clients outlook gets correctly handled, even if they're from random port?

Comment: Hi Pitto, the `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE` should do the trick. Basically this will do NAT for every port. If this works you can restrict it step by step. But the first step is to test if it works that way for your setup in general.